# Shiro: where credential should be stored?

Tags: security, rest, credentials, shiro

**Little prehistory:**

I develop RESTful services. That services receives requests from the web frontend and resends it to another server with the actual business logic. I use Shiro to protect my services. Problem is that some business logic functions require a user password. Of course, I can store password in my principal, but I think it is not correct to store credentials there.

**Question**

So, what is the conceptual right place where I should store credentials to have access inside my REST services?

**Update**

Ok, I can also store passwords in Shiro sessions, but i don't think that it is the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the info is kept in an implementation of AuthenticationToken. This interface has two method: getPrincipal (for example login or email) and getCredentials(). The last is usually used to store a password.

If you look at class UsernamePasswordToken, which is an implementation of this interface, you see that the two are indeed used for username and password.

Now what we did is extend the class AuthorizingRealm for our own authentication mechanism and in the authentication method we store the token in the principal.

```
@Override
public AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) {
... authentication logic

    SimplePrincipalCollection principalCollection = new SimplePrincipalCollection(login, realmName);
    principalCollection.add(token, realmName);

    SimpleAuthenticationInfo simpleAuthenticationInfo = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(principalCollection, login.getPasswordHash());
    return simpleAuthenticationInfo;
}
```

Now you can get the token later:

```
    PrincipalCollection principals = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipals();
    AuthenticationToken token = principals.oneByType(AuthenticationToken.class);
```

Comment: How I understand **AuthenticationToken** or **AuthenticationInfo** entities use only during authenticate process and then do not store in application (I think it happens for security reasons). So, it is impossible to get them after authentication. As said [here](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Get-AuthenticationInfo-From-Subject-td5003710.html), it's look like Principal and Session is only entities where we can store some additional user-related information.

Comment: I guess I wasn't complete enough, updated the answer with more info.